# Hide a message after 5000 milliseconds with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want if a message(`div class="message"`) there is (mean was `display: block;`) after 5000 milliseconds it is hide(`display: none;`). how is it?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SLRFt/1/

```
<div class="message">This is a message</div>

setTimeout(function(){ $('.message').fadeOut('slow'); }, 5000);
```

Comment: 5000 seconds = about 1.5 hours. Did you mean 5000 microseconds?

Comment: please rephrase your question because it is very unclear what you are asking actually.

Comment: @IvanGL: 5000 microseconds = 0.005 seconds.

Comment: oh yes, i mean is microseconds.

Comment: @Dennis: I know, but in original question there was 5000 seconds.

Comment: @IvanGL: Yes, but 5000 **micro** seconds are only 0.005 seconds. It sould have said 5000 **milli** seconds which is 5 seconds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('.message').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xavi3r/SLRFt/3/

Comment: keep in mind that delay is added since jquery 1.4 if you are using older versions you would need to upgrade or use the setTimeout technique.